# Get the last 50 lines from text file using php

Tags: php, file, text

I have a text file such as a log file, and I want to get the last 50 lines from that.

How can I do it, in PHP?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could also be using "tail" if you are on linux.

```
$handle = popen("tail -50l YOUR_FILE_HERE 2>&1", 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    echo "$buffer<br/>\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
pclose($handle);
```

Comment: BSD has them too. And I'm not sure, but I think Macs have some basic Unix utilities like those too (not like someone would run an OS X server on production, but...).

Answer (score 2):

There are [some sollutions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) in comments for function `fseek`.

Comment: i checked could not get any solutions

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$data = file('yourfile.txt');
$lines = implode("\r\n",array_slice($data,count($data)-51,50));
?>
```

As simple as this

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use fopen to get the handle, then use filesize to get the size and fseek to go to filesize-50. Then it's just fread of 50 characters to get the last 50. I imagine this ha been done before if you look at the manual under fseek.

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php#86517) is the solution in the fseek manual entry. Just change the -1 on the fseek line to -50.