# Reading ONLY the last 50 lines of a large text file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a pretty large log file on my server, and i would like to have a continually updating console view on my website, showing only the last 50 or so lines of the file

the problem is that it takes too long to load the entire file every time, so i need a way to load only the nescsarry lines, (if possible) or another solution that works.

thanks in advance

Comment: You could use something like `exec('tail')`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's an [exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848045/get-the-last-50-lines-from-text-file-using-php) (as John Conde mentioned), unless you want to do it client-side, in which case maaaybe, just maybe, you could do it with [HTTP byte serving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving).

I do recommend you do this with PHP, so read that question.

Comment: so the post John linked to, also includes updating the file, i might have missed out on that part

Answer (score -1):

```
$file = file("file.txt");
for ($i = count($file)-50; $i < count($file); $i++) {
echo $file[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Untested, but...?

Comment: that's php thou, not sure i can make that update continually

Comment: This will update continually. When you put it in a page and open the page, it will get the last 50 lines no matter what. Also you tagged it as `php`, so...