# Get last 5 lines from a large file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the last 5 lines from a large file using JavaScript

I've tried a lot to do it. Like this:

```
<script>
    $.get( "myfile.txt", function(data) {
      $( "#MyDiv" ).html(data.split("\n").slice(-5).join("\n"));
    })
</script>
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

Which should show the contents into `MyDiv` but it show them on one line.

Comment: [Perhaps this could shed some light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493783/javascript-reading-only-the-last-x-amount-of-lines-of-large-server-text-file)?

Comment: Join them with `<br>` instead

Comment: @Phiter - I've tried that, but same.

Comment: Looks like a document ready issue, with the script being above the html

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks in HTML are `<br>`. So:

```
$( "#MyDiv" ).html(data.split("\n").slice(-5).join("<br>"));
```

Comment: That did it. I was adding `<br>` in `data.split()` too :/ Thank you very much! Accepting the answer once I can.